# Windows minimised by default and not restored on taskbar click

Tags: windows-10, window

I'm having issues on windows 10 with one account where apps with multiple windows start those windows minimized.

Specifically a new document will:

- start minimized
- will not restore size when double-clicking on task bar
- will show up after a right-click on the task bar + restore from menu

More context:

- two screen remote desktop
- tablet mode is not enabled
- issue is account-specific (no other users on the server are affected)
- (speculation) issue began after the user started connecting from both a laptop and a 2-screen desktop, but affects both
- this is persistent across relogins / reboots

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the items are minimized and not retored/windowed *off-screen*? When you:

- Launch a problem app
- Hover over the taskbar icon
- Right-click the thumbnail preview when it appears

What window-state options are available & which are disabled? The current state is the option that's disabled:

[image]

If the context menu indicates your app is restored/windows but it's not visible, it's restoring to cooridinates outside the viewable area. To remedy:

1. Hover & right-click the preview as before
2. Select the **Move** command
3. Play with the keyboard arrow keys until the window comes into view
4. Grab with mouse & resize/position as desired.